# How to fix 'else' outputting more than 1 outcome

Tags: python

Very basic problem, trying to output if a number is divisible by 3/5/both/none but else will return 2 statements when they are not true. How do I fix this?

I've tried to move where the else is indented, first time it wouldn't output for the numbers that are not multiples of 3 or 5 and second time it would output two answers.

```
while True:
    z = input("Please enter a number- to end the program enter z as -1 ")
    if z % 3 == 0 and z % 5 ==0:
        print("Your number is a multiple of 3 and 5")
    elif z % 3 == 0 and z % 5 != 0:
        print("Your number is a multiple of 3")
    elif  z % 3 != 0 and z % 5 ==0:
        print("Your number  is a multiple of 5")
    if z == -1:
        break
   else:
       print("Your number is not a multiple of 3 or 5")
```

I.e. if 67 is entered `Your number is not a multiple of 3 or 5` as expected. But if 15 is entered `Your number is a multiple of 3 and 5` and `Your number is not a multiple of 3 or 5` is the unexpected output.

Comment: Also you need to type cast the input via `int(z)`. Currently it is a string.

Comment: You probably want the `z == -1` test to be the *first* test. That way the rest of the code should correctly distinguish the cases (provided you align the `else` with `elif`.

Comment: You are *break*ing way too late

Comment: Related tag: [tag:fizzbuzz]

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse I guess OP is using Python 2. Otherwise, they would get an exception and not just a duplicate output

Comment: so you are getting multiple messages because you are using more then one if senteces. First is `if elif elif` and the second is `if else`. So this they if you right any number which is not -1 you will get `Your number is <correct answer>` + `Your number is not multiple by 3 and 5`.

Answer (score 2):

If you incorporate all the comment suggestions so far you get something like this:

```
while True:
    z = input("Please enter a number- to end the program enter z as -1 ")
    # cast to int
    z = int(z)
    # break early
    if z == -1:
        break
    elif z % 3 == 0 and z % 5 == 0:
        print("Your number is a multiple of 3 and 5")
    elif z % 3 == 0:
        print("Your number is a multiple of 3")
    elif z % 5 == 0:
        print("Your number is a multiple of 5")
    else:
        print("Your number is not a multiple of 3 or 5")
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, why does it matter where the break part goes?

Comment: It doesn't. It just helps layout your code and intent. I added it in as part of the "summary of comment suggestions"

Comment: What's more important was that your check for -1 did not form part of your check for 3 and 5 multiples, hence, both checks ran. Moving -1 check up with a break means you no longer have to waste valuable CPU cycles checking multiple first.

Comment: That makes sense - so if there is ever a break test it should always go first?

Comment: It doesn't have to. Sometimes it doesn't make sense. Sorry, there is no general rule. In this case, there is no point in claculating multiples for -1 when clearly the user is done.

Comment: @chepner thanks for the edit :) I hadn't got round to play with the logic yet.

Comment: @ChristopherBurt In general, you want to order your tests so that you do the least amount of work: do cheap tests and likely-to-pass tests early. This is subject to the semantics of your tests: for instance, one test may only be safe if a second test passes, so that constrains the order in which the two tests can run.

Answer (score 0):

By initiating a new `if` block you are ending the preceding `elif` chain.

```
if z == -1:
    break
else:
    print("Your number is not a multiple of 3 or 5")
```

As @Daniel Junglas comment said, you should structure it like this:

```
z = input("Please enter a number- to end the program enter z as -1 ")
if z == -1:
    break
elif (z % 3 == 0) and (z % 5 == 0):
    print("Your number is a multiple of 3 and 5")
elif (z % 3 == 0) and (z % 5 != 0):
    print("Your number is a multiple of 3")
elif (z % 3 != 0) and (z % 5 == 0):
    print("Your number  is a multiple of 5")
else:
    print("Your number is not a multiple of 3 or 5")
```

Comment: You forgot to cast to int: `z = int(input(...))`

Comment: Whoops, actually OP seems to be using Python 2 since they're not getting an error. So they should use `z = int(raw_input(...))`

Comment: Well it works without casting for me in Python 2 so I'll just leave it out as it isn't really important to the answer of the asked question.